# How to find absolute min/max of $f(x)=x^3+3x^2-24x+1$ on $[-1,4]$

Tags: calculus

I need to find the absolute min and absolute max.

The attempt at a solution
I first took the derivative, reduced, and set it to equal $0$ to find crit numbers.
$x^2+2x-8=0$
Factored.
$(x+4)(x-2) = 0$
so $x=-4$ or $x=2$ but since $-4$ is not on the interval i threw it out and kept $2$ as my only crit #
I plugged in my critical number along with my LB and RB numbers to find:
Aboslute Max. to be $(-1,23)$
Absolute Min. to be $(2,-27)$

Am I doing this correctly? This was a take home quiz given in my calculus class and I want to make sure it is correct before I turn it in.

Comment: maximum is 27 right?

Comment: yes the Maximum is right and will attained for $$x=-1$$

Comment: The question is to find max and min of $ \mid f(x) \mid $ right?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: @stud_iisc why $|f(x)|$?

Comment: absolute maximum means maximum over the whole interval, as to differ from local maximum @stud_iisc

Answer (score 0):

The function is, when considered over $\mathbb{R}$, increasing over $(-\infty,-4]$, decreasing over $[-4,2]$, increasing over $[2,\infty)$.

You're interested in $[-1,4]$; the function is decreasing over $[-1,2]$ and increasing over $[2,4]$. Therefore the absolute minimum will be for $x=2$; the maximum will be at one of the extremes: since
$$
f(-1)=27,
\qquad
f(4)=17
$$
you have the answer.

Comment: The question is to find max and min of $\mid f(x) \mid$ right? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks in advance Sir.

Comment: not the absolute value, just the function itself...